# DStream checkpointing has been enabled but the DStreams with their functions are not serializable

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I want to send DStream to Kafka , but it doesn't still work.

```
searchWordCountsDStream.foreachRDD(rdd =>
rdd.foreachPartition(

    partitionOfRecords =>
    {
      val props = new HashMap[String, Object]()

      props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, outbroker)

      props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
        "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
      props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
        "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
      val producer = new KafkaProducer[String,String](props)

      partitionOfRecords.foreach
      {
        case (x:String,y:String)=>{
          println(x)
          val message=new ProducerRecord[String, String](outtopic,null,x)
          producer.send(message)
        }
      }
      producer.close()
    })
)
```

this is some error info :

> 16/10/31 14:44:15 ERROR StreamingContext: Error starting the context,
>   marking it as stopped java.io.NotSerializableException: DStream
>   checkpointing has been enabled but the DStreams with their functions
>   are not serializable spider.app.job.MeetMonitor Serialization stack:
>     - object not serializable (class: spider.app.job.MeetMonitor, value: spider.app.job.MeetMonitor@433c6abb)
>     - field (class: spider.app.job.MeetMonitor$$anonfun$createContext$2, name: $outer, type: class spider.app.job.MeetMonitor)
>     - object (class spider.app.job.MeetMonitor$$anonfun$createContext$2, )
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3,
>   name: cleanedF$1, type: interface scala.Function1)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3,
>   )
>     - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream, org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream@3ac3f6f)
>     - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStreamCheckpointData)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStreamCheckpointData, [ 0
>   checkpoint files
>
> ])
>     - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream, org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream@6f9c5048)
>     - element of array (index: 0)
>     - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 16)
>     - field (class: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer, name: array, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
>     - object (class scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer, ArrayBuffer(org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream@6f9c5048,
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream@3ac3f6f))
>     - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStreamCheckpointData)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStreamCheckpointData, [ 0
>   checkpoint files
>
> ])

Comment: What is `MeetMonitor`?

Comment: it is my main object

Comment: Show us your `createContext` method.

Comment: val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MeetMonitor")
    if (AppConfigContral.Spark_model == "standalone")
      sparkConf.setMaster(AppConfigContral.Spark_master)
    else if (AppConfigContral.Spark_model == "yarn")
      sparkConf.setMaster("yarn")
    else
      sparkConf.setMaster("local[2]")

    var ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(interval))
    ssc.checkpoint(checkpoint)

Comment: Is that *all* you're doing? Because Spark is trying to serialize your main object for some reason, and I see nothing wrong with the code you added here (you should really append it to the question). Show us the entire Spark DAG (the way you declare the transformations).

Comment: Oh, my god. what should I do for that .I have no any ides .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127028/discussion-between-yuval-itzchakov-and-kof).

Comment: @Kof: please copy your code line here (starting `val sparkConf`) and add it to your question. As you can see it does not format well in a comment. Finally, to keep things tidy, please delete the comment.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and found an answer here

https://forums.databricks.com/questions/382/why-is-my-spark-streaming-application-throwing-a-n.html

It seems that using checkpoint with foreachRDD causes the problem. After removing checkpoint in my code, everything is fine.

P/S. I just want to comment, but I do not have enough reputation to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with Spark 2.3.0 version and encountered same issue, I got it resolved just by implementing Serializable interface for the class it was throwing error.

In your case it spider.app.job.MeetMonitor should be implementing it like:.

public class MeetMonitor implements Serializable {

//
...
}

Another thing if you are making use of Logger in your class, please note that it's instance is also not serializable hence could cause the same issue. 
This could also be resolved by defining it as:

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(.class);